# `debootstrap` or `chroot` with `fakeroot[-ng]` instead of `sudo`: is it right or wrong?

Tags: permissions, chroot, debootstrap

#### Background

I wanted to use `debootsrap` with `fakeroot-ng`. It started fine, but later on `debootsrap` stopped with an error and I had a dialogue box reporting `tar` crashed.

However, as I had some application crash since my recent upgrade from Ubuntu 12.04 to 14.04, I'm not sure about why this crashed.

#### Question

Normally, in principle, should this be OK to use `debootstrap` in a `fakeroot[-ng]` session or is this to only be used as a real root user?

I wonder the same about `chroot`.